# Expand links to posts in flags inline

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools, flag-queue

I was staring down an evil-looking flag the other day, and it had a bunch of links in it like this:

[image]

Currently, to handle this I have to:

1. take a deep breath
2. click on the first link
3. Go back to the flag queue and click the first link again, holding command so it opens in a new tab
4. Evaluate and take action
5. Click next link
6. Repeat 5 and 4 until all the links are clicked and handled.

This is tedious and tends to spawn nasty evil things called tabs:

[image]

Therefore, I propose that we allow **opening links inline** in the flag queue. I'm imagining something like this:

- We add little dropdown indicators next to links to SE posts:

  > [image]

  (these would look better in practice, I just stole a dropdown indicator from another part of the page)
- Upon clicking one of these dropdown things, we would get an inline view of the post like we do for flags now:

  > [image]

Thoughts/opinions? Would this help clear flags faster?

Comment: I just added a script at Stack Apps; [View questions & answers inline from any comment or post!](http://stackapps.com/q/6690/26088). You may be interested :) If you could check to see the container of the mod message comments section thing (the thing in your screenshot), I could make it work for the mod section as well! (I would, but I'm not a mod anywhere `:(`)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I'll go test this in a second - want to post this as an answer?

Comment: did this work for the mod section? :) (just curious!)

Comment: Haven't had a chance to test yet, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a userscript to expand links to posts inline, from comments or questions/answers.

[image]

This userscript adds small arrows next to links to posts on the same site. Clicking them will cause a box to be added below, containing the actual post! Just like it does in the profile 'actions' tab (and others).

See more at the Stack Apps post: [View questions & answers inline from any comment or post!](https://stackapps.com/q/6690/26088).

BTW, this won't work for the mod tools right now, but if you could inspect the element surrounding those links, and post a screenshot, I could tweak it to work for mod tools as well! (I would if I could, but I'm not a mod anywhere...)

Answer (score -1):

This suggested feature would certainly be nice if such link-heavy flags were common. I have a couple concerns that should be probably be considered if the feature is to be implemented:

1. It seems to me that the example flag shown in the question should actually not be a custom flag. Flagging each individual question would be better because each could be marked helpful or declined, and because some types of flags don't always require valuable time in front of moderators' eyes. Basically, I'm concerned that this feature would encourage suboptimal flagging behavior.
2. Should the drop-down arrow appearance be restricted to just links inside Stack Exchange? There might be browser exploits in external pages. (Compromising a moderator account would be a motherlode!) I'm concerned that the convenience of the arrow might lead moderators to drop their guard and forget to check the real target of the link by mousing over it.